# Display of a level in js view according to quiz score

Tags: html, vue.js

On a small project, I am starting in view js, however being very close to the goal, I block. I would like to display a level (there are several) on the browser according to the score obtained in the quiz, I found some small clues but in application it does not work. How can I get there?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fkgoj5xc/

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

      <title>Jeux JS QUIZZ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>{{ quiz.title }}</h1>
      <!-- index is used to check with current question index -->
      <div v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions">
        <!-- Hide all questions, show only the one with index === to current question index -->
        <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
          <h2>{{ question.text }}</h2>
          <ol>
            <li v-for="response in question.responses">
              <label>
                <!-- The radio button has three new directives -->
                <!-- v-bind:value sets "value" to "true" if the response is correct -->
                <!-- v-bind:name sets "name" to question index to group answers by question -->
                <!-- v-model creates binding with userResponses -->
                <input type="radio" 
                       v-bind:value="response.correct" 
                       v-bind:name="index" 
                       v-model="userResponses[index]"> {{response.text}}
              </label>
            </li>
          </ol>

          <button v-on:click="next">
            next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-show="questionIndex === quiz.questions.length">
        <h2>
        Quiz finished
      </h2>
        <p>
          Total score: {{ score() }} / {{ quiz.questions.length }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the js/vue js

```
// Create a quiz object with a title and two questions.
// A question has one or more answer, and one or more is valid.

var quiz = {
    title: 'Quiz Jeux Simplon JS',
    questions: [
      {
        text: "Informatique, web et numérique : est-ce la même chose ? (10 points)",
        responses: [
          {text: 'Oui',
           value: "0"  }, 
          {text: 'Non', correct: true,
           value: "10" }, 
        ]
      }, {
        text: "Que veut dire HTML ? (20 points)",
        responses: [
          {text: 'Un logiciel (High Term Mixed Logiweb)',
        value: "0" }, 
          {text: 'Un langage (HyperText Markup Language)', correct: true,
        value: "20" },
          {text: 'Un langage (High Term Middle Language)',
        value: "0" },
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "Parmi la liste suivante, lequel n'est pas un navigateur web ? (30 points)",
        responses: [
            {text: 'Google', correct: true,
        value: "30" },
            {text: 'Opéra',
        value: "0" },
            {text: 'Netscape',
        value: "0" },
        ]
          },
          {
              text: "Que veut dire margin 10 px ? (40 points)",
              responses: [
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a une bordure extérieure de 10 pixel',
                value: "0" },
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a une bordure intérieure de 10 pixel',
                value: "0" },
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a un espacement extérieur de 10 pixel', correct: true,
                value: "40" },
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a un espacement intérieur de 10 pixel',
                value: "0" },
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
  ;

 var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quiz: quiz,
    // Store current question index
    questionIndex: 0,
    // An array initialized with "false" values for each question
    // It means: "did the user answered correctly to the question n?" "no".
    userResponses: Array(quiz.questions.length).fill(false)
  },
  // The view will trigger these methods on click
  methods: {
    // Go to next question
    next: function() {
      this.questionIndex++;
      console.log(this.userResponses);
    },

    // Return "true" count in userResponses
   /* score: function() {
      return this.userResponses.filter(function(val) { return val }).length;
    }
  }*/

  // test //

  score: function() {

    var score = this.userResponses / this.quiz.questions.length
      if (score >= 80) {

        return "Vous êtes niveau avancé, je code ! " 
      }

      else if (score <=70 ) {
        return "Vous êtes niveau intermédiaire, j'approfondis !"
      }
      else if (score <= 40) {
        return "Vous êtes niveau débutant, je découvre !"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI you have two ending `</body></html>` tag

Comment: yes i just fixed it thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a version with the final text at the end of the quizz.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfwpq1vy/2/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

      <title>Jeux JS QUIZZ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>{{ quiz.title }}</h1>
      <!-- index is used to check with current question index -->
      <div v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions">
        <!-- Hide all questions, show only the one with index === to current question index -->
        <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
          <span class="step">
      Question N°{{ index }}
      </span>
      <span class="total">
      total :{{ score() }}
      </span>
         <h2>{{ question.text }}</h2>
          <ol>
            <li v-for="response in question.responses">
              <label>
                <!-- The radio button has three new directives -->
                <!-- v-bind:value sets "value" to "true" if the response is correct -->
                <!-- v-bind:name sets "name" to question index to group answers by question -->
                <!-- v-model creates binding with userResponses -->
                <input type="radio" 
                       v-bind:value="response.correct" 
                       v-bind:name="index" 
                       v-model="userResponses[index]"> {{response.text}}
              </label>
            </li>
          </ol>

          <button v-on:click="next">
            next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-show="questionIndex === quiz.questions.length">
        <h2>
        Quiz finished
      </h2>
        <p>
          Total score: {{ score() }} / {{ quiz.questions.length }}
        </p>
        <p>
        {{ showtxtend() }}
        </p>


      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Create a quiz object with a title and two questions.
// A question has one or more answer, and one or more is valid.


var quiz = {
    title: 'Quiz Jeux Simplon JS',
    questions: [
      {
        text: "Informatique, web et numérique : est-ce la même chose ? (10 points)",
        responses: [
          {text: 'Oui',
           value: "0"  }, 
          {text: 'Non', correct: true,
           value: "10" }, 
        ]
      }, {
        text: "Que veut dire HTML ? (20 points)",
        responses: [
          {text: 'Un logiciel (High Term Mixed Logiweb)',
        value: "0" }, 
          {text: 'Un langage (HyperText Markup Language)', correct: true,
        value: "20" },
          {text: 'Un langage (High Term Middle Language)',
        value: "0" },
        ]
    },


    {
        text: "Parmi la liste suivante, lequel n'est pas un navigateur web ? (30 points)",
        responses: [
            {text: 'Google', correct: true,
        value: "30" },
            {text: 'Opéra',
        value: "0" },
            {text: 'Netscape',
        value: "0" },
        ]
          },
          {
              text: "Que veut dire margin 10 px ? (40 points)",
              responses: [
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a une bordure extérieure de 10 pixel',
                value: "0" },
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a une bordure intérieure de 10 pixel',
                value: "0" },
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a un espacement extérieur de 10 pixel', correct: true,
                value: "40" },
                  {text: 'Le bloc HTML a un espacement intérieur de 10 pixel',
                value: "0" },
              ]
          }
        ]
      } 

  ;

 var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    quiz: quiz,
    txtend: 'txtend',
    // Store current question index
    questionIndex: 0,
    // An array initialized with "false" values for each question
    // It means: "did the user answered correctly to the question n?" "no".
    userResponses: Array(quiz.questions.length).fill(false)
  },
  // The view will trigger these methods on click
  methods: {
    // Go to next question
    next: function() {
      this.questionIndex++;

      console.log(this.userResponses);
    },

   showtxtend: function() {
      var txt;
      var score_ = this.userResponses.filter(function(val) { return val }).length
      if (score_ >= 4) {

       txt = "Vous êtes niveau avancé, je code ! " 
      }

      else if (score_ <=2 ) {
       txt = "Vous êtes niveau intermédiaire, j'approfondis !"
      }
      else if (score_ <= 1) {
        txt = "Vous êtes niveau débutant, je découvre !"
      }
      return  txt ;
    },

    // Return "true" count in userResponses
    score: function() {

      return this.userResponses.filter(function(val) { return val }).length;
    }
  },

  // test //



});
```

Comment: Hello thank you :)

In fact I would like very much that the correct answers be calculated and then according to the number of points obtained this shows me either: level 1, level 2 etc (these levels correspond to a number of points obtained), I will try to arrange my worries ..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm going to watch this but I just tested it and it's perfect, thank you very much !!

Comment: i m glad if it works as expected, if yes thanks to accept my answer